# Access members of inner class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, class, serialization, deserialization

I tried finding way of this seemingly easy task but with no success. Sorry I'm new to oop and c#. Pardon if it's trivial.
I have to access `verb` in following class.

```
public class testclass
{
 public class selector
  {
    public static string verb { get; set; }
  }
  //some other classes here
 }
```

One api class deserliazes and return an object of testclass.

```
var res = apicall(); //retruns testclass object
```

I want to access verb and retrieve it's value. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you try :`Selector.Verb` after creating a instance of Selector?

Comment: @Zaphod There is a seperate class file for testclass. I have to access the verb in different file where i am getting res object. How can I do it. Selector.verb directly is not valid.

Comment: `testclass.selector.verb` is valid - although you should fix the names to match normal naming conventions :)

Comment: @NWard: No, you absolutely do *not* need to create an instance of `selector`; `verb` is a static property.

Comment: You're right, I misread the OP's code and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that is a *static* property, you access it as:

```
string str = testclass.selector.verb;
```

Note that the access has nothing to the with the instance returned by `apicall()`.

---

EDIT: if `verb` were not a static member, then you'd need an instance of `selector` defined somewhere to access that member. For example:

```
public class TestClass
{
     public class Selector
     {
          public string Verb{ get; set; }
     }

     public Selector SomeSelector {get; set;}  
 }
```

Now you have a member of type `selector`, which you can access like:

```
 var res = apicall();
 var str = res.SomeSelector;
```

Comment: How do I get value returned in that object?

Comment: @Maxsteel there is no value "in that object". since `verb` is a static property, its value is _independent_ of any objects.

Comment: Got it. Assume it's not static, then how do I access it?

Comment: `mySelector` must be public.

Comment: @gmailuser generally, yes. Unless you're within a `TestClass` method/constructor ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can access verb with:

```
testclass.selector.verb
```

because it is a static property which means it is defined to this specific type and not an object.

BUT, if you want to be point to verb with the res object, you will need to define the type for the res variable, otherwise the compiler will not let you compile this code. example:

```
testclass res = apicall();
```